# CSS spec: css visual formatting model box generation

Tags: css

I'm brand new in CSS and currently reading the [CSS spec visual formating model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html). I'm having a hard time conceptualizing which type (block or inline) boxes are generated and which formatting context they are using. Based on my understanding I've made this summary, I would like to know if this is correct and if not could you please tell me where I'm wrong and why. I've used BFC and IFC as acronyms for "Block formatting context" and "Inline formatting context".

```
  <div> <!-- generate a block-level box with BFC -->
    <p>some text</p>  <!-- generate a block-level box with IFC --> 
  </div> 
  <div><!-- generate a block-level box with BFC -->
    <p>some text</p> <!-- generate a block-level box with IFC --> 
    some text        <!-- generate a anonymous block-level box with ifc --> 
  </div> 
  <div> <!-- generate a block-level box with BFC -->
    <p>some text</p> <!-- generate a block-level box with IFC --> 
    <span>some text</span> <!-- generate an anonymous block-level box with IFC containing an inline-level box with IFC --> 
  </div> 
  <div><!-- generate a block-level box with BFC -->
    <p> some text </p> <!-- generate a block-level box with IFC --> 
    some text <span>some text</span> <!-- generate an anonymous block-level box with IFC containing an anonymous inline-level box with IFC and a inline-level box with IFC --> 
  </div> 
  <div> <!-- generate a block-level box with IFC -->
    <span>some text</span> <!-- generate a inline-level box with IFC -->
  </div> 
  <div><!-- generate a block-level box with IFC -->
    some text <span> some text </span> some text <!-- generate a anonymous inline-level box with IFC, an inline-level box with IFC, and again an anonymous box-level with IFC -->   
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds correct to me ....